# Como usar dois viewports OpenGL usando QT?

Tags: qt, opengl, viewport

Estou tentando fazer dois viewports no qt mas não estou obtendo sucesso, abaixo segue o código:

**1. Método que faz os desenhos na tela:**

```
void GLWidget::paintGL()
{
    //Limpa buffer
    //glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    //Funcao que indica que vou usar vertices e que quero deslocar objetos
    //Permite fazer rotação, translação e escala
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

    //Le matriz identidade
    glLoadIdentity();

    //parametro face: Especifica os poligonos para o qual 'mode' se aplica
    //parametro mode: especifica como os poligonos serão rasterizados
    glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_FILL); //GL_FILL, GL_LINE, GL_POINT

    /* GL_POINTS */

    //faz transformação linear do tipo translação (move objeto)
    //Configuração um novo sistema de coordenadas onde vai ser desenhado
    glTranslatef(-7.0f, 5.0f, -8.0f);

    //glPointSize(6.0f);

    glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

    glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
    glVertex2f(0.0f, 0.0f);
    glVertex2f(1.0f, 0.0f);
    glVertex2f(1.0f, 1.0f);
    glVertex2f(0.0f, 1.0f);
    glEnd();

    glLoadIdentity();
    glTranslatef(-5.0f, 3.0f, -7.0f);

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glColor3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    glVertex2f(0.0f, 0.0f);
    glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glVertex2f(1.0f, 0.0f);
    glColor3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    glVertex2f(1.0f, 1.0f);
    glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    glVertex2f(0.0f, 1.0f);
    glEnd();

    glLoadIdentity();
    glTranslatef(-5.0f, 3.0f, -8.0f);

    /* GL_TRIANGLES, GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, GL_TRIANGLE_FAN */

    glLoadIdentity();
    glTranslatef(-3.0f, 1.0f, -8.0f);

    glColor3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
    glVertex2f( 1.0f, 1.5f);
    glVertex2f( 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glVertex2f( 2.0f, 0.0f);
    glEnd();

    glLoadIdentity();
    glTranslatef(-3.0f, 1.0f, -8.0f);

    glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
    glVertex2f(0.0f, 1.0f);
    glVertex2f(1.0f, -1.0f);
    glVertex2f(2.0f, 1.0f);
    glEnd();

    glLoadIdentity();
    glTranslatef(4.5f, -5.0f, -8.0f);

    glColor3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

    float radius = 0.9f; //radiano Ã© o tamanho entre o centro e o uma borda. O tamanho do circulo
    float Pi = 3.141592653589793238462643383279502884f;

    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN);

    //glVertex2f(origemX, origemY);

    for(int i = 0; i <= 360; i++) {
        glVertex2f(radius * cos(i * Pi/180), //cosseno refere-se a X
                   radius * sin(i * Pi/180)); // seno refere-se a Y
    }

    glEnd();

    glFlush();
    //glFinish();
}
```

**2. Método que faz os viewports:**

```
void GLWidget::resizeGL( int w, int h)//w e h são as dimensões novas da janela
{    

    glClear (GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);                              // Clear Screen

    for(int viewportIs=1;viewportIs<=2;viewportIs++){
        switch (viewportIs)
        {
        case 1:

            glViewport     ( 0, 0, w/2, h); //primeiros dois parametros são o inicio da viewport
            //para este método, x e y (0,0) especificam o ponto |||inferior esquerdo|||

            //diz que o modo é matrix de projeto. Ela configura o que vai ser enxergado
            glMatrixMode   (GL_PROJECTION);
            glLoadIdentity ();

            if ( h==0 )  // Calcula Aspect Ratio da janela
                gluPerspective ( 80, ( float ) w, 1.0, 5000.0 ); // define altura, largura, profundidade da janela
            else
                gluPerspective ( 80, ( float ) w / ( float ) h, 1.0, 5000.0 );


            //muda para projeção ortogonal (2D)
            //gluOrtho2D

            //gluPerspective e gluOrtho2D são de uma biblioteca util que chamam OpenGL por trás

            //esse metodo abaixo foi chamado aqui apenas por garantia que o padrao é GL_MODELVIEW
            //glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
            //glLoadIdentity();

            break;

            /* Segundo viewport */

        case 2:

            glViewport(w/2, 0, w/2, h);

            glMatrixMode   (GL_PROJECTION );

            glLoadIdentity ();

            if ( h==0 )  // Calcula Aspect Ratio da janela
                gluPerspective ( 80, ( float ) w, 1.0, 500 ); // define altura, largura, profundidade da janela
            else
                gluPerspective ( 80, ( float ) w / ( float ) h, 1.0, 500 );

            break;

        }
    }

    glClear (GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);                          // Clear Depth Buffer

}
```

O que acontece, é que ele divide a tela em duas, mas mostra apenas em um local os desenhos.

No meu código eu tenho um `switch case`, e se eu deixo o mesmo da maneira que está aparece apenas no segundo `viewport`, conforme imagem abaixo.

[image: Viewport 1]

Fazendo um teste a alterando **case 2:** para **case 3:**, o que faz não entrar na segunda parte, os desenhos são pintados apenas no `viewport` 1, conforme a imagem abaixo.

[image: Viewport 2]

Pela lógica, ele está limpando a tela a cada `viewport`, por isso fica só o segundo, mas não sei como resolver isso.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O que acontece é que quando a janela do programa abre, primeiro é chamada a função *resizeGL*, depois a *paintGL*. Nesse caso, o desenho vai ser feito sempre sobre o último viewport especificado, o que é confirmado pelos teus dois exemplos.

Se você quiser que o desenho seja feito nos dois viewports, você vai precisar chamar a função de desenho duas vezes, uma para cada viewport. Você pode fazer o seguinte:

1. Colocar as rotinas de desenho dos objetos numa função separada;
2. Mover o código que tá em *resizeGL* para *paintGL*;
3. No final de cada *case*, chamar a função criada em 1.

Talvez essa não seja a solução mais elegante, mas acho que deu pra você entender a ideia.